# How can i do wrapping of child elements inside Flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to do wrapping of child elements inside flexbox container but setting up height in percentages (for .wrap, .block and .mini)? Like here - http://jsfiddle.net/4cghpvyo/19/, but in % to make it responsive. Or any other idea how to make it responsive?

```
.wrap {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
    width: 30%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.mini {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: just set `height: 25%` on the `.mini` class, it works for me. You can set `height: 100%` on the `.block` class too.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne did you change height of Flex container as well? Because now its 500px; If you change to %, it doesnt work

Comment: You didn't say anything about the container in your question :). But if you want to use percentages for the container you have to make sure that the parent of that container has a set height.

Comment: @LGSon Sorry for that. But all given answers didnt help me to solve the problem. So i posted a solution which worked for me. Because i cant set the height of container as it changes all the tim when user resize the window

Comment: Both answers fixed that, and mine had 2 options, where one used a wrapper and were completely dynamic, but then you change the original requirements, by letting us know through comments. Instead update the question properly and allow for users to adjust their answers. ... Also, you now say _cant set the height of container_, but in your answer you say _Height needs to be set on wrap container_, which contradicts itself. Furthermore, if you post the actual solution (which you should for a proper answer), we would be able to adjust when see what worked, as `float` is often not the best solution

Comment: @LGSoni updates the question. Now it says that all divs needs to have height set up in percentages. I know that float is not the best solution :(

Comment: @LGSon Here is new jsfiddle when i set all heights in % - http://jsfiddle.net/MariiaOleksiuk/j94ubsz9/

Comment: @MaryOleksiuk Well, those percentage based height doesn't work. Remove the text, or text in some, and you'll see it all, or those being empty, collapse into nothing. Also, that layout doesn't even look like the one you posted in the question.

Comment: @LGSon so only solution is to use float?

Comment: No, `float` on children also need its parent to have a height, and if percent is used, its parent need a height, and so on, which my first sample show. My second show how content effect height, i.e. with an image, and with Flexbox it all size's nicely, and with no height at all on `wrap`. I posted my answer back. Read it carefully and you'll see what can and need to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewport units (`vh`/`vw`) is commonly used to give a parent a responsive but fixed height, where percent on its children will work, though can sometimes not be possible.

For `height: 100%` to work on the `wrap`, its parent need a set height (or being position absolute), and if the parent also use percent, its parent need a height, and so on, until the `html` element is reached, which height is set to the viewport's height.

Here showed by applying height to the `html` and `body`.

For the items it then becomes simple, and in your case, the `block` set to 100% and the `mini` to 25%, both columns will fill the parent height.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.mini {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
</div>
```

---

Based on a comment, you mentioned that `block` might contain different sized images that should make up for the height, then with the given markup and using flex *column* direction, that won't be possible, as flex *column* items need its parent to have a fixed height, or else they won't wrap.

A simple solution to the problem would be to set the `wrap`'s flex direction to `row`, add an extra element around the `mini`'s (`inner-wrap`) and make it a flex column container.

```css
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.block img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner-wrap {
    width: 70%;   
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.mini {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```